# Query about C# namespaces and using

Tags: c#, namespaces

Newbie C# question about using & namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace Granite2 {
    class Class1 {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Conn1;
        SqlClient.SqlConnection Conn2;
    }
}
```

Conn1 line, not surprisingly, compiles fine. Conn2 has an error "The type or namespace 'SqlClient' can't be found".

Why is this? I thought having "using System.Data" in there would mean I could reference SqlClient without the full qualifier.

I'm perplexed because I'm converting VB.NET to C# and the namespace works in VB.NET. Obviously some nuance I'm not aware of here.

Comment: No you need to specify full namespace except for the case above if your class `Class1` is in namespace `System.Data` which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because C# compiler only imports types in namespace you've specified (for your particular case `System.Data`), but not from all children namespaces of it (so in your case `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace types were not imported).

As from [FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-don-t-namespace-using-directives-import-nested-namespaces.aspx) of C# team - main reason of doing so is protection against collisions between namespace names.

Just imagine - your namespace `X` can has children namespaces `Y` and `Z` both having `SomeClass` declared. So if you will `using X` and then `SomeClass с = new SomeClass();` - there will be collision if compiler will import all types from all children namespaces of `X`.

Comment: Thanks for the reference - there is a comment that VB.NET has the behaviour of importing child namespaces which explains the difference. Although the comment is old, it looks like it's still the case with VB.NET in VS2013